# Canonicalizing/verbosifying software names?

Tags: discussion

Every time I write "Cura" in a question or answer, it gets edited to "Ultimaker Cura", [most recently](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/10940/11157) resulting in awkward verbose repetition that required additional edits to fix. I don't see any justification for requiring use of official verbose names for software products that can be clearly identified by a well-known shorter name. For example on computing SE sites we don't force users to write "Microsoft Windows" or "Redhat Linux" in contexts where "Windows" or "Redhat" would be understood. And even on this site I don't recall every mention of "Ender 3" getting edited into "Creality Ender 3".

Is such a policy (it's effectively a policy, since it's enforced by edits made by a moderator) appropriate for this site?

For what it's worth, as a new-ish contributor to this SE site, having nitpicky edits to all of my posts does not make me feel welcome and appreciated.

Comment: I can see what you mean, but I am sure that any such edits are meant with good intention, and are not intended to annoy anyone or make them feel unwelcome.  We like to try to keep this particular SE site correct (be that grammatically, SI units and the correct spacing, or brand names or what have you). However, you raise a valid point, w.r.t. the manufacturer, and we'll take note in future. Cheers :-)

Comment: Indeed, I don't think the intention is bad. But it ends up being irritating and with a result that's objectively neither better nor worse, just gratutitously difference from what the author originally wrote.

Comment: All good points and quite understandable... BTW, thanks for your input and contributions to the site - the more active members the better, and we might actually make it out of beta (one day)..! :-D

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the input (+1) very much appreciated! First of all it is never the intention to annoy or irritate people, my apologies if it is experienced as such! Small edits are sometimes necessary to get out some spelling and unit spacing errors to improve the layout and readability of the questions and answers. I think the edits to the software name are born from my own experiences and nuisance as an owner of a software product that is misspelled many, many times, even by my own management... You've definitely got a point when it is seen as a nuisance and should therefore not be done anymore.

Do note that the software initially was called Cura and the name was changed by the developers to explicitly include the company name at some point (version 2.something), hence the changes. I guess it would be best to use the complete name when one refers to the installment version, but can be shortened when referred to in text.

Comment: Personally I don't like the units changes either - replacing space with `&nbsp;` is ugly and makes the markdown hard to read/edit, contrary to the whole purpose of markdown, and I don't even consider a space between the last digit and °C to be proper style - I always learned the degree sign goes immediately "on" the digit. But these are all matters of formatting style where it's easy for me to accept that the site mods want a polished uniformity, even if it's not one I agree with, much like a common indentation style in a codebase.

Comment: @R. - Please read [Don't forget the space!](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297/dont-forget-the-space). It is the [international standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units#General_rules). The ° is adjacent to the quantity *only* for angular measurements... that surprised me too. You *could* use the unicode non-breaking space character (`U+00A0`/`\xa0`/`ALT255`), but as that is invisible, it's virtually impossible to tell if it is there or not. BTW, if you have anything that you wish to discuss, you can join us in [chat].

Comment: @Greenonline: Fair enough. This probably has some relation to my being one of the folks who refuses to say kibibytes. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

One additional point, that I've just remembered... we've also renamed the [cura](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cura) tag, to [ultimaker-cura](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimaker-cura), although, we *have* kept the [cura](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cura) tag as a synonym to [ultimaker-cura](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimaker-cura), so as not to break anything (i.e. links from either external sites or within SE itself). Thanks go to Trish for pointing that out.

Please see [Tag Maintenance Summer 2019](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/tag-maintenance-summer-2019)